# Convert html to json in php laravel

Tags: php, json, facebook, laravel-5, jsonencoder

Im hitting this url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1843624489016097?fields=link&access_token=EAAD3ZBKkIhYMBAL3KRi9eZBXlYJADZARRFMSe0Nc35WTP92X2etkccVqnjNcjJgKbd8ABtX5pyDPN0nAA7jORyjpOGexZCYp1Sf2iw0DJjCf8UkPiLwhuApSGDGZBvy5w7vk3U0Ba97FZA2DO7J4m4UjvbIolDaRP9TRpemEmLyQZDZD
```

with the below code in php,

```
$url ='https://graph.facebook.com/' . $connection->provider_id . '?fields=link&access_token=' . $connection->token;
$ch = curl_init($url);
$json= curl_exec ($ch);
```

I have this html coming from Facebook, I want to use only "Link" in this,

`{"link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/YXNpZADpBWEdrUlJiUzc0SWFWZATI4SEVJUmJHTTJQVHU2M3owcTJLOHh5MnJYOTI0LWdMT3VFUC1veXNWdXBhM3o3RzdkQmV4cjNfTC1nSkdheGFhV19pWWU5T1ZAWSzlkN0NBTUl4NVZAKTE9oRjlFbjdObU5i\/","id":"1686741234967769"}1`

I tried converting that into JSON but its not working, Its coming in same format, since im doing this in a API, im checking this under Postman,  I did like this..

`$request = json_encode($json, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);`

The format is not getting convert to json, Im doing in PHP Laravel.

Comment: What do do you mean by convert to HTML? Have you ran `json_deocde` instead of `json_encode`? What is the expected output?

Comment: You are making barely any sense here. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a 1 at the end of the output, possibly you're echoing something extra that you shouldn't .

I suspect you expect curl to return the actual result but you are not using the appropriate flag. The reason I suspect that is because you are assigning the return result to `$json` but without the flag `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`will return `true` and not any json value.

Here's what you can try:

```
$url ='https://graph.facebook.com/' . $connection->provider_id . '?fields=link&access_token=' . $connection->token;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER);
$json= curl_exec ($ch);

$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
$link = $jsonArray["link"];
```

More information on the curl flags in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in place of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). So you should try like:

```
$request = json_decode($json, true);

$link = $request["link"];
```

Also use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` to save response in variable just after `curl_init`.

Comment: Answer Updated!